# Unity Markerless Geolocation AR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geolocation, mapbox, augmented-reality

I am working on a game (project) in augmented reality using Unity. I am making this game like when the user starts the game, it assigns user a new location where on reaching he can find and collect artifacts which are augmented. Can anyone tell me which SDK is to use or how to do it?

Also, I am considering to do it with MapBox SDK. But I am a very much beginner in this and don't know anything about this.

Comment: It would be easier to assist if you included what code you have right now and where exactly you're having problems.

Comment: Use GPS location and ArKit/ArCore. Or start with something simple to begin with like a space shooter or Arkanoid.

Comment: I can Augment a single object at a specific location using mathew hallberg's script of AR markerless UFO tutorial... All i want to know is that how can i assign area to users in which the 3D objects are Augmented... Like, game assign user a new area away from his current position like 50 meters on the right and the objects are Augmented there.